# Automatic redirect issue in iframe

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

I have an iframe links  within an html page as shown below:

```
    <TABLE border="0" width="900">
    <tr valign="top">
    <td width="300" ALIGN=center>
            <div class="item_list">
            <a href="http://www.skiholidayextras.com?   affiliate_id=172&amp;submit_to=http://www.skihautesavoie.fr/results-lift-pass.html" target="_blank">link</a>
            </div>
    </td>
    <td width="300" ALIGN=center>
            <div class="item_list">
            <iframe src = 'http://www.flipkart.com/affiliate/displayWidget?affrid=WRID-137232779171598318' frameborder = 0, height=250, width = 300 > </iframe></a><br>
            </div>
    </td>
    <td width="300" ALIGN=center>
            <div class="item_list">
            <iframe src = 'http://www.flipkart.com/affiliate/displayWidget?affrid=WRID-137232785207215857' frameborder = 0, height=250, width = 300 > </iframe>
```

Now when i click within an iframe link , it open the link, but when i click back, it automatically redirect me to that iframe link. Can anyone suggest me what's the problem i'am having?

Comment: I'm not able to get what behavior do you want. Can you explain the expected result?

Comment: @vivek  see when  i click on             <iframe src = 'http://www.flipkart.com/affiliate/displayWidget?affrid=WRID-137232779171598318' frameborder = 0, height=250, width = 300 > </iframe></a><br>
 this link , i lead to http://www.flipkart.com/affiliate/displayWidget?affrid=WRID-137232779171598318  , but when i go back from here to my main page, i automatically redirected to the above link,  hope you understand?

Comment: I think elen answered what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would implement my own controls for each iframe. Delegate this work to some buttons on your page instead:

```
<div id="view_iframe">
    <iframe id="viewer" name="viewer" width="100%" height="600" src="some.html">
         <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    <input type="button" id="back" class="button" onClick="viewer.history.back();" value="<<" />
    <input type="button" id="frwrd" class="button" onClick="viewer.history.forward();" value=">>" />
</div>
```

note - `viewer` is iframe id

note that both buttons, are positioned absolutely to align with iframe on page resize.

anyway, here are what the iframe controls for this:

```
// For an iframe's window
iframe.contentWindow.history.back(); 
iframe.contentWindow.history.forward();
```

or

```
iframe.contentWindow.history.go(-1); // back
iframe.contentWindow.history.go(1);  // forward
```

Comment: is it possible to implement this task without using  control buttons?

Comment: @user2656285 to be honest, I can't see how it's possible, especially when you have multiple iframes unless you completely override normal browser flow for these events... but perhaps someone else got better answer

Comment: hey you know how to open iframe link on another tab?

Comment: the whole point of iframe so you can display content of a different page within a page....